# Unable to pull data from Redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I store the data in the Redux store. I can see it using Redux-DevTools that initially it is null, but when I refresh page the data is in the store. However when I tried to pull that data in one of my components, it is not working. I'm getting error "undefined".

> Error: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')"

```js
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import VideoBackground from "./VideoBackground";

const Container = () => {
  const movie = useSelector(store => store.mymovies?.nowPlayingMovies)

  if (movie == null) return

  const newMovie = movie[0]
  console.log(newMovie)

  return (
    <div>
      <VideoBackground />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Container
```

I try to pull movies data of `index[0]`. When I use early return it always return from the 5th line, but the movies data is in the store. It is not null after the refresh. So why the code is not moving forward after the 5th line when the data it is already in the Redux store?

Comment: The selected `store.mymovies?.nowPlayingMovies` value is undefined. Are you sure of (a) the state that is stored and (b) the state that is selected? Please [edit] to provide a complete [mcve].

Comment: `null` and `undefined` are not the same value. The code explicitly checks for a `null` `movie` value, `undefined` will not trigger an early return. We need more details. Can you [edit] to include the redux code and where/how the Redux store is populated/updated?

Answer (score 0):

Just add console and check the state value in `Container` component. Also, spell check the state properties (`mymovies` & `nowPlayingMovies`).

Not sure how the state value is used inside this component and I hope the below code might be the expected one.

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import VideoBackground from "./VideoBackground";

const Container = () => {
  const movie = useSelector((store) => store.mymovies?.nowPlayingMovies);
  console.log(movie) // add this console & see what's the value for second time
    
  const newMovie = movie && movie.length ? movie[0] : null;
  console.log(newMovie);

  return <div>{newMovie && <VideoBackground movie={newMovie} />}</div>;
};

export default Container;
```

Comment: I tried this but getting null in the console , and again i checked redux Devtools , the data is there .